# How to interpret CPU time vs CPU percentage

Tags: performance, azure, cpu-usage

When I check azure monitoring tool, CPU usages are shown in CPU time

```
min: 4.69s  
max: 2008.08 s  
avg : 207.63 s
```

I am familiar with CPU% which makes sense as in application requiring cpu cycles.

how does the above time correspond to percentage?
What would be the max in seconds which corresponds to 70 or 100% cpu usage?

note : cpu is 4 cores

On a different instance, I noticed in a 60 second window

```
min: 0
max : 133.83
avg : 19.61
```

Based on below answers (see Nachiket's explanation in comments as well)
133.83 is a product of cpu time multiplied by cores ( in my case 4 cores)

Cpu utilization in this case is 133.83/(60*4) = 54.1%

Comment: A CPU% is only meaningful on a desktop machine with a fixed number of processors.  It is meaningless in a data center with virtualized hardware.

Comment: @HansPassant Azure web app scale-out rules show the label "CPU %" with a 0-100 slider.

Comment: I wish Azure showed CPU% as well. It'd be faster to see if CPU usage is a bottleneck, without having to do the math of CPU time.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Some cloud monitoring tools give resource usage in standard time measures. (seconds, hours, days etc.)

If you have usage in seconds like,

```
min: 4.69s  
max: 2008.08 s  
avg : 207.63 s
```

Then you can find out usage in % from above using definition of %.

```
% utilization = (resource used time / total resource availability time)
```

ex: if cpu was available for 100 seconds and out of that 80 seconds it was used then

```
% utilization = 80/100 = 80% CPU utilization
```

From your given time, total available time is missing. Find that out and use above formula.

```
% utilization = avg. usage/total availability
```

no. of cores shouldn't matter as that is present in both cases.

```
% utilization = ( (no. of cores * avg util)/(no. of core * total availability))
```

I am not sure about azure cloud monitoring but if it is providing same then you can use it.

Comment: in azure, resource availability time are in ranges of 1 minute and 1 hour only. Based on your answer, 2008 seconds / 1 hour (which is 3600 seconds)  = 55.8% . thank you.

Comment: Today I saw cpu time = 69.78 seconds in 60 seconds duration. As per above calculation cpu utilization is 116%. Please comment.

Comment: First of all, its not my calculation, its standard utilization law.(I just explained it to you in simple terms) Second, Its Illogical saying for 60 seconds duration test CPU utilization was 69.78 seconds for a single core machine (divide 69.78 by no. of cores or multiply 60 by no. of cores If you have many cores. Then that should be used as utilization per core and avg of all as avg utilization) Third, I don't mind you removed accepted answer tag :) but I think you should learn to analyze and apply whatever taught to you.

Comment: i see your answer stating independent of cores. however your comments are 'depends on cores'. could you clear that ambiguity

Comment: Yes. I think second point in prev. comment should clear your confusion. Simple example could be, You can't say in a day I work for 25 hours (Illogical, no need to prove it) Thus if a you run a test let say for 1 hr then maximum time you can use a resource with 100% usage is 1hr. You cant exceed that. It can exceed if you have multiple core which you are not taking into consideration.

Comment: In your case suppose you have 2 core machine and your time is 69.78 seconds then 2 cases are possible, 1. divide your total time into per core usage (time/cores) 2. you have not measured cpu util correctly. Please check which case you fall in.

Comment: I see 130 seconds cpu usage in 60 seconds total available time. Based on above discussion its logical to conclude, azure is giving cpu time multiplied  by cores. Hence cpu usage would be 130/(60*4) = 54.1% Thank you for your time once again

Comment: I am glad that you understood :)