# How to retrieve total system CPU usage from Windows in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, operating-system, cpu-usage, msdn

I need to retrieve total CPU usage on the fly for a feedback system to change the behavior based on whether CPU is getting throttled or not. For this, I looked into `NtQuerySystemInformation` sys call which provides system information at any given time but it seems like this function has been deprecated in the latest versions of Windows since MSDN page says

> [NtQuerySystemInformation may be altered or unavailable in future
>   versions of Windows. Applications should use the alternate functions
>   listed in this topic.]

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724509(v=vs.85).aspx

Does anyone know what OS versions this call is supported on? Win 7/8/8.1/10? Is there any other way to directly retrieve total CPU usage?

Comment: Helpful reading: [How to determine CPU and memory consumption from inside a process?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process) Probably even a dupe, but not sure enough to lodge a close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Officaially, there are two functions are in the MSDN.

1. GetSystemTimes(): It looks more easier but posted a long time ago. 
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724400(v=vs.85).aspx
2. GetSystemInfo() : I've got the sample code from https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Use-PerformanceCounter-to-272d57a1

   ```
    DWORD GetProcessorCount() 
    {
         SYSTEM_INFO sysinfo;  
         DWORD dwNumberOfProcessors; 
         GetSystemInfo(&sysinfo); 
         dwNumberOfProcessors = sysinfo.dwNumberOfProcessors; 
         return dwNumberOfProcessors; 
    } 
    vector<PCTSTR> GetValidCounterNames() 
    { 
        vector<PCTSTR> validCounterNames; 
        DWORD dwNumberOfProcessors = GetProcessorCount(); 
        DWORD index; 
        vector<PCTSTR> vszProcessNames; 
        TCHAR * szCounterName; 
        validCounterNames.push_back(TEXT("\\Processor(_Total)\\% Processor Time")); 
        validCounterNames.push_back(TEXT("\\Processor(_Total)\\% Idle Time")); 
        // skip some codes
        return validCounterNames;
    }
   ```

Good Luck !

In my opinion, Windows command "tasklist /v " will show the CPU TIME and MEMORY from the OS and you can call the command through 'system' or other functions.

PS. I still think looking at the OS side is the best way for monitoring CPU usage. (If I use the function, it will also do the same thing inside.)

Comment: Strongly recommend summarizing the link or providing enough in formation for future readers to find the content again when the link rots.

Comment: Okay You're right. I added some information in there.

Comment: `tasklist /v` does not show CPU usage.  "CPU Time" is not the same as CPU usage.

Comment: Those are the same but different expression. Please Refer,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240978/how-to-interpret-cpu-time-vs-cpu-percentage

Comment: Thanks @Kwang-ChunKang. This solution worked for me. :)