# Linux terminal measure cpu usage of a command

Tags: linux, bash

Id like to measure the cpu usage during the execution of a command. If I type `$ cp BigFile Location` Id like to see how much this process used cpu power

Comment: `time cp Location`, will give you processing time, what metric are you after?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone but i need the cpu usage in percent

Comment: You might be interested in this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/554/how-to-monitor-cpu-memory-usage-of-a-single-process

Comment: percent is a rolling average :/ if it takes 20mins how would 15% make sense, some details on conversion from time to utilisation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240978/how-to-interpret-cpu-time-vs-cpu-percentage)

Comment: I need a min and average and a high value

Comment: I need a tool which does the same thing as time but for cpu usage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently found a tool which measures time, cpu usage, memory usage all at once. Its called `/usr/bin/time` and should be installed via `apt`

Answer (score 1):

`htop` is a graphical solution in the shell - maybe this one helps

There you can search for it.

Answer (score 0):

`top` command will show you memory and CPU usage,

you can pipe with grep

```
top | grep chrome  # for google chrome cpu and mem usage for and example
```

Comment: that works but how do i check the usage from a command within a script and store it into a file or smth

Comment: cant you use PID ?

Comment: but how does the script know when to stop monitoring

Comment: how about giving approximate time loop : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176284/time-condition-loop-in-shell

Comment: would work but for a script... its not the most elegant way

Comment: I need a tool which does the same thing as time but for cpu usage

Comment: this might help 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321440/how-can-i-check-to-see-if-a-process-is-stopped-from-the-command-line