# What does the Y axis represent in CPU usage of Azure Container Instances

Tags: azure, metrics, azure-container-instances

I see a CPU usage chart where I wanted to view the MAX.
We have 2 containers in a group, both are configured to have 1 vCPU.

[image]

There is a spike at the start of above 200. What does that represent?

[image]

Comment: That you have more than 1 vCPU :-). It is an accumulation over all vCPU's

Comment: I think it is milliseconds. Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240978/how-to-interpret-cpu-time-vs-cpu-percentage

Comment: @PeterBons yes we have 2 containers running in that group with 1 vCPU configured for each. Would that mean that Azure allocated more than configured for a short duration? Of would the CPU time explanation make more sense?